# GDB C++ Not possible to get source core line when error (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb

I have couple of days dealing with a Segmentation Fault error and I'm not capable to found it. I'm using gdb to debug it but GDB is not giving me any details fo the line where error is happening.

Now, I am generating a error just to ensure my build is compatible with GDB. I'm compiling using cmake with degub enabled: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` and I also ensured -g flag is enables in `CMakeFiles/SmartGate.dir/flags.make` and I manually added -ggdb flag.

I used `make VERBOSE=1 SmartGate` to ensure flags are present in compilation and linking process and they are.

I'm able to load my build in gdb:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) file  SmartGate
Reading symbols from SmartGate...
```

And I also capable to show SourceCode where injeted error is present:

```
(gdb) l SmartGate.cpp:30
25      sqlite3 *db;
26  
27      std::string tmp_db = NULL;//"controller_test_data.db";
28      int rc = sqlite3_open(tmp_db.c_str(), &db);
29      if (rc)
30      {
31          spdlog::error("Can't open database: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
32          sqlite3_close(db);
33          exit(1);
34      }
(gdb)
```

But when error happened, I only get the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/pi/SmartGate/build/SmartGate 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xab33a1e0 (LWP 12870)]
[New Thread 0xaa2591e0 (LWP 12871)]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Thread 1 "SmartGate" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb3e3ef24 in raise () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb3e3ef24 in raise () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0xb3e2a230 in abort () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

This is the error output for the actual error I want to trace:

```
Thread 1 "SmartGate" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6fb9c1c in memcpy () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6fb9c1c in memcpy () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Any advice?

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint on `abort` ? I get a good stacktrace by doing so (on windows)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, the abort error is just an example of the ouput with no source of the error. Do you have any suggestion for SIGSEGV?

Comment: looks that the stack has been corrupted. You have no choice than to try to find what action triggers this (using "print" traces and line by line step, and some time to spare)

Answer (score -2):

Your question is about unwinding from segmentation fault, but your example about unwinding from `abort()`. These are completely separate things (in other words, the answer to the question about your contrived example is unlikely to help with your *actual* problem).

> `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid`
> I only get the following backtrace:

What's happening here:

1. Your code calls equivalent of `std::string foo(nullptr);`
2. `std::string` constructor detects this bug in your program and throws exception
3. Since you don't have a `catch` block, `std::terminate()` is called, which
4. eventually calls `abort()`
5. GDB is having trouble unwinding the stack to the point where `abort()` was called.

There are several ways you can avoid the need to unwind stack from `abort()`.

1. Audit places in your program which construct new `std::string` instances, make sure none of them pass `nullptr` as an argument.
2. Set breakpoint on `std::string::string(const char *s)` constructor. Make it conditional on `s == NULL`.
3. Ask GDB to stop when exception is thrown with `catch throw` command. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html).
4. You can rebuild your `libc.so.6` with debug info, or install `libc6-dbg` or similar package from your distribution. This *might* help GDB to unwind from `abort()`.

Comment: As I menttioned in the post. It is an injected error. If you check the code, the correct input for string  is commented next to the NULL value.

Comment: @MiguelResendiz Yes, I know. Please read the first and the last statement of the answer.